# Why is my empty sparsbundle so big (1,5 GB)?

Tags: time-machine, encryption, sparsebundle

I just followed the instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/12354/31395) to create a encrypted sparseimage for Time Machine backups. The empty sparsebundle ended up being 1.4 GB (and after enabling encryption it grow to 1.6GB). Why is an empty sparseimage so big?

Comment: Is the purpose of it to "reserve" the space as set during the set up?