# How to encrypt external network drive timemachine backup

Tags: macos, network, backup, time-machine, encryption

I am following this:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-nas-windows-share-time-machine-backup/

Which basically says that you have to create a sparse disk image and put that on your external network drive and mount it.

I create the sparse image with disk utility:

[image]

Notice that I chose 128 bit encryption for the sparse image.

I add that to my network drive and mount it.

Once I do that I have to tell timemachine to use that disk:

> sudo tmutil setdestination /Volumes/TimeMachine

That works great, when I open timemachine it is setup with that disk and I can perform backups.

**However** when the backup starts I get a warning that I am backing up an encrypted drive to an unencrypted disk:

[image]

Normally if you can find the drive on the network through the TimeMachine UI, there is a checkbox to encrypt your backups.  However when using *tmutil* on the command line I do not believe that there is an option for that.

Is there a way I can get time machine to perform encrypted backups using this method?

If not is there a way that I can mount this external network drive in such a way that the TimeMachine UI will be able to see it on the network so I can select it as a backup drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypting/protecting Time Machine backup drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11345/encrypting-protecting-time-machine-backup-drive)

Comment: Really just explains how to encrypt the sparse bundle.  Which is what I already did.  Still get a warning that I am backing up to an unencrypted drive